# AWS DMS Include database name on target message

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, event-sourcing, aws-dms

Im making some event sourcing using dms, and i need to include dbname on the metadata that is sent from some postgresql databases to kinesis (as target) i got here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Tablesettings.html

i runned out of ideas.
Adding a tag with dbname to the message probably works too but i cant find some precise documentation of how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible route is to add a prefix to the schema or rename the schema. Just add the database name with a delimiter so you can easily parse it out.

Take a look at the first example on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.html

Comment: yes, i edited the schema, that solution worked but sounds a bit dirty

Comment: Unfortunately I've been trying to figure out this same issue and that's the only solution I could get working.

Dirty? I suppose it's not ideal but does it do the job? Yes. :)